# Attaching or stitching image piece at a particular position using python

Tags: python, image, image-processing, data-extraction, pymupdf

I am extracting images from a given pdf file using python library PyMuPDF. The images that are constructed in a single layer they are being extracted perfectly. But Images which have been constructed using multiple layers they are being extracted in pieces. Every piece of the image is being treated as a separate image. I tried to get the coordinate of the image boxes and made an analysis that if the starting of a single coordinate of one image is adjacent to the ending of another then they should be stitched together at that **particular position**. Is there a way I can achieve that goal?

Comment: It is definitely possible to join using coordinates. Can you share some sample images I can try with?

Comment: @AmitAmola I have pdf and extracting images from it. I will share the source code and the file.